# Delete a row from Parse Table

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a table called Favourite tags. it has fields - Tag, User( Pointer- respectiv user objectid).where User can store a tag and along with user-objectid as pointer in user filed and user remove the tag from favourite

For Storing/Updating: it is working fine .

```
           ParseObject favtagobject = new ParseObject("Favourite");
            favtagobject.put("Tag", "#" + keyword);
                favtagobject.put("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                favtagobject.saveInBackground();
```

For removing/deleting the tag from table: Below code is not working

```
           ParseObject favtagobject = new ParseObject("Favourite");
             favtagobject.put("Tag", "#" + keyword);
                favtagobject.put("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                favtagobject.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(com.parse.ParseException arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("deleted the tag succesfully");
                    }
                });
```

i want to delete a row from table i know which row to be deleted. Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried to first retrieve the object from the database? And then call .deleteInBackground on the parseObject that you retrieved?

Comment: U mean I have to run a query and then do a delete operation ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, when you use 'new ParseObject("Favourite");' it will construct a new ParseObject. This parseObject does not exist in your database until you call any variant of .save() on it. Hence when you do this

```
    ParseObject favtagobject = new ParseObject("Favourite");
         favtagobject.put("Tag", "#" + keyword);
            favtagobject.put("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            favtagobject.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(com.parse.ParseException arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("deleted the tag succesfully");
                }
            });
```

All you're doing is creating a new object, that does not exist in your database and then try to delete it?  What you're looking for is this

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Favourite");
    query.whereEqualTo("Tag", "#" + keyword);
    query.whereEqualTo("User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.getFirstInBackground(new FindCallBack() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, com.parse.ParseException arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   object.delete();
                   object.saveInBackground();
            }
        }););
```

This will first get the object from your database and then delete the row from table and save the changes made to the object!

Comment: Haha. My stupidity at peaks ! Thanks  Ru ! to delete entire row  use delete() method .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bart de Ruijter. This is also works for me.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Objects");
    query.getInBackground(objectID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

            try {
                object.delete();
                object.saveInBackground();

                Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashboardActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successuly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(dashboard);

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```