# Delete a row from Parse Installation Table From android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've set up parse and push notification is working perfectly fine.

What I am trying to achieve is, to delete a row (installation instance) containing an old 'installationId'. When app is re-installed a new installationId is generated and after saving the new installationId in my own server, I want the android device to delete the row from parse db that contained the old id.

I've followed two tutorials :

i) [Delete a row from Parse Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564162/delete-a-row-from-parse-table)
ii) https://www.parse.com/questions/delete-row

Codes - (according to 1st tutorial) :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Installation");
        query.whereEqualTo("installationId", "9702fcb1-5912-43fa-9248-5f18bd398485");
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                try {
                    parseObject.delete();
                    parseObject.saveEventually();
                }catch(ParseException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Error (Logcat):

```
4052-4052/com.pbc.pchakraverti.enotice E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pbc.pchakraverti.enotice, PID: 4052
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.parse.ParseObject.delete()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.pchakraverti.enotice.clgIdVerificationActivity$1.done(clgIdVerificationActivity.java:68)
            at com.example.pchakraverti.enotice.clgIdVerificationActivity$1.done(clgIdVerificationActivity.java:64)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**Code - According to Parse Documentation:**

```
ParseObject.createWithoutData("Installation", "IHgT4Gbszs").deleteEventually();
```

And in this case, there is no exception, but the row doesn't get deleted!

I am targeting the 'Installation' class of parse.
[image: Parse Installation Class]

*Update*

```
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("installationId", "9702fcb1-5912-43fa-9248-5f18bd398485");
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseInstallation>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseInstallation parseInstallation, ParseException e) {
                try {
                    parseInstallation.delete();
                    parseInstallation.saveInBackground();
                }catch(ParseException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

This code runs without problem, but the entry isn't deleted from parse server.

Comment: In my not-so-good experience (wiith Parse), I've seen it take time to reflect some changes. This obviously doesn't answer your question, but it is a suggestion to try waiting for some time for the changes to show, unless you already have.

Comment: Will keep that in mind!! But no chance as of now!

Comment: You could try to save with a callback (I hope they still have that function) and log the event. You'll know if the code to save the row/update/deletion has or hasn't completed successfully.

Comment: @Priyabrata Did you figure out the solution for this issue ?

Comment: Nope. I didn't. Everything I tried failed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `ParseInstallation.getQuery()` instead of `ParseQuery.getQuery("Installation")`.

Comment: I've updated the code as per your suggestion. This runs without exception, but the corresponding entry isn't getting deleted.

Comment: The code you posted also doesn't check for an exception in the `GetCallback`. You should check if that is null before proceeding with the deletion, and log the error if it isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to do that

this line of code:

```
ParseObject parseObject = ParseInstallation.getQuery().getFirst();
```

throws exception:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.
```